# PDF doesn't look like the HTML page it's generated off

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I want to create a PDF of a web page. I am using jsPdf for this. It creates a PDF of the web page but the PDF doesn't look the same as the web page it is based on. Everything has changed, such as; font size, text alignment and table alignment. Some of the html code has also appeared in PDF document.

How can I generate a PDF that looks like my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can render any page as a PDF by adding the renderAs attribute to the  component, and specifying “pdf” as the rendering service. For example:

Visualforce pages rendered as PDFs will either display in the browser or download as a PDF file, depending on your browser settings.

Regards,

Naveen

SSE

http://www.autorabit.com